# How come the index of min return two elements in a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, user-input

I am trying to conduct a search in Python (just like how I would vlookup in Excel) by getting the index position of a value (Service_Length) and passing it onto another variable, (Staff).

```
#Find the index position of max value
max = (df[df['service_length'] == max_val].index.values)
#Return the element in max
max = (max.tolist())

#Find index position of min value
min = (df[df['service_length'] == min_val].index.values)
#Return the element in min
min = (min.tolist())

#Find index position of average value
mean = (df[df['service_length'] == mean_val].index.values)
#Return the element in min
mean = (mean.tolist())

print(max)
print(min)
print(mean)
```

The output is:
[238]
[43, 57] <--- How come this has two values? When intuitively there should be just 1 min value in the df?
[210]

Comment: Why intuitively there should be only 1 min value... ? If your dataset has twice the same value, then you are going to get two index values

Comment: Good point! Can I ask, given the output in a list format, how can I utilise these output to search in the Staff dataframe to find the staff name of these indexes?

Comment: Note that you are returning the index of the min and max values and not the values themselves

Comment: Also, in the title you refer to mean but in the question, you refer to min. Which one returns two?

Comment: Hi @gtomer, thanks I've made the edit. Indeed, "min" returns two. To your point above, how can I instead return the values themselves?

Comment: If you want the values, just use `.min()`

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code to get the values:

```
#Find index position of min value
min = (df[df['service_length'] == min_val].values)
#Return the element in min
min = (min.tolist())
```

or just:

```
df['service_length'].min()
```

This will give you just one min value, even if appears more than once

To leave only the 70years old in the dataframe you should:

```
df70 = df[df['age'] == 70]
df70
```

This will create a new dataframe with rows of 70 years old only.

Comment: Hmm but I'd like to query the minimum value(s) on anther dataframe called "Staff" to find out who had the min service length? E.g. "Min Service Length = Adam Hicks"

Comment: Then please explain better what are you trying to do

Comment: Haha I'm sorry! So basically the dataset has many variables (e.g. Staff Name, Staff Age, Staff Service Length etc). Just for example, I have found the oldest staff (i.e. max age) which is 70 years old. Now, I would like to input 70 years old into the dataset, and find out the name of the staff.

Comment: @codes -  See corrected answer above.